# Using Array.prototype.filter() and Array.prototype.map()

Tags: javascript

I need to first filter items for an array of objects `{type: 'genre', value: '123'}` and after combine in a string content for property `value` only.

Any suggestions on how to improve the following code?

```
this.flattenCategories = function () {
    // flatten in a single string all categories so to be easily visaulised in the dom
    var categories = this.information.filter(function (item) {
        if (item.type === 'genre') {
            return item;
        }
    });
    this.categoriesFlatten = categories.map(function (item) {
        return item.value;
    }).join(CONFIG.app.categoriesSeparator)
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would replace the `filter` and the `map` by a `reduce`:

```
this.flattenCategories = function () {
  // flatten in a single string all categories so to be easily visualised in the dom
  return this.information.reduce( function( categories , item ){
    if( item.type === 'genre' ){
      categories.push( item.value );
    }
    return categories;
  }, []).join(CONFIG.app.categoriesSeparator);
},
```

This way your code is still functional, you loop over the data only once, and your intent is clearer.

`categoriesSeparator` seems such a specific constant that I wonder if you collect all your constants in 1 single place, J2EE style.. That's not really idiomatic JavaScript, try to define your constant closer to where you will actually use it.

Answer (score 4):

You have a bug in your code. Filter expects true or false. Your still works because implicit type conversion of Javascript (object => true, undefined => false).

Correct would be:

```
var categories = this.information.filter(function (item) {
    return item.type === 'genre';
});
```

Filter/Map could be combined together if you like.

You're using variable from outside. You could improve testability and readability by using of arguments and return the result.

```
this.flattenCategories = function (information, separator) {
    // flatten in a single string all categories so to be easily visaulised in the dom
    return information
        .filter(function (item) { return item.type === 'genre'; })
        .map(function (item) { return item.value; })
        .join(separator);
}
```